# Accessing Client-Side arrays on Server Side ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have few `int` and `string` arrays at client side javascript.

How can i access them on server-side in a button click handler of asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid approach would be to serialize them and assign it to a `runat="server"` hidden field. You'll be able then to access the array deserializing `Value` property.

You can easily  handle serialization with json format or comma separated values.